# ArrayAdapter for array within ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

im trying to populate listview with an arrayadapter

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    int numOfArray=3;
    float val= (float) 5.23;
    String b="col";
    String c="usd";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] mView;



        List<String[]> mString = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<numOfArray; i++) {

            mView = new String[3];
            mView[0] = c;
            mView[1] = b;
            mView[2] = String.valueOf(val);
            mString.add(mView);
        }




        ListAdapter mAdapter = new custom_adapter(this, mString);
        ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

and the adapter

```
class custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    public custom_adapter(Context context, List<String[]> mString) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list,mString);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);


        String[] mString = (String[]) getItem(position);



        TextView mText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);mText.setText(??);
        ImageView mImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.image);mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
        return customView;

    }


}
```

the problem is i am using an array within the arraylist. i tried to pass it into another string[] but getting an error on get().

```
String[] mString = (String[]) getItem(position);
String[] aString = mString; aString.get(0);
```

i have been searching on how to get the element value of these array within arraylist to fill a textview, but i cant get any answer or refrence to do it.

any answer or refrence will help. tyvm.

Comment: aString is an array, there is no get method on array. Use aString[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant use methods on arrays "aString.get(0)", instead you should use "aString[0]".

So this:

```
String[] mString = (String[]) getItem(position);
String[] aString = mString; **aString.get(0);**
```

Should be like this:

```
String[] mString = (String[]) getItem(position);
String[] aString = mString;
**String value = aString[0];**
```

Whas this your question? I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are not getting the `arraylist` values through `constuctor` like this
 See your mistake

```
this.mStringarray=mString;
```

and to set here like this

```
mText.setText(mStringarray[position]);
```

Use the below code now

```
 class custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    String[] mStringarray;
        public custom_adapter(Context context, List<String[]> mString) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_list,mString);
             this.mStringarray=mString;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View customView =  mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);


            TextView mText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mText.setText(mStringarray[position]);
            ImageView mImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.image);mImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
            return customView;

        }


    }
```

Comment: maybe my way of asking was a bit confusing. but im trying to get an element of array within an arraylist. not from the arraylist. ty for the response @quick